# Package (free or commercial) for building GUI for standalone Java based Application

Tags: java, user-interface

I am looking to build a Java based GUI oriented stand alone application. I have already tried SWT and Swing but the GUI layout lacks the polished look and feel of commercial applications such as the cd/dvd burning software Nero.

Can someone recommend a GUI building library that can be incorporated into Java based applications? Commercial GUI packages are also fine.

Note: This is a standalone application and not web based.

Comment: Has anyone used MVC mediator? I got referred to in an offline email. http://www.danmich.com/mvcmediator/1.0/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt used to have some java bindings (http://qt.nokia.com) not sure if they still do.

You may also want to look into other free or commercial Look & Feel implementations, which can make Swing look quite polished.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/) in the past although the coding was in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [nimbus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html). It's the less ugly Swing look and feel.